# Convert image (jpg) to video.avi not working in IIS

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, iis-7

I'm Using accord.video.VFW.dll for convert image (jpg) to video.

And install WMV 9 vcm for compress/Decompress.

Its working fine in my local machine Video was created (.avi) format ..Then my code is a move to live(IIS) .same code, DLL and WMV 9 vcm was installed. But it returns error(failed creating compressed stream).

its need to chance any IIS permission ??? or any other issue..??

Comment: I think you need to install on your server the video codecs used by accord.video.VFW.dll, it probably use some windows X default codec video that are not present in Windows Server, is that possibile?

Comment: Your needed codec seems to be that according to the developer site: https://www.fourcc.org/downloads/

Comment: already  install wmv 9 vcm codec in server machine .In server machine ,localhost working fine.But not in live..

Comment: your project target is x86? Because years ago i read somewhere that VFW stuff will not work in 64 bit mode on 64 bit OS. But that not explain why it works in localhost :(